# exist any fast way of join images to video faster?

Tags: image, join, video, ffmpeg, mp4

Im using ffmpeg but takes more than 10minutes to convert 2000 images to mp4

```
ffmpeg -y -r 1/5 -f concat -safe 0 -i ffmcommand.txt -c:v libx264 -vf  fps=25,format=yuv420p out22.mp4
```

how I could do faster please help me

Comment: The preset parameters, resolution, framerate and output bitrate/quality will affect the transcoding speed. And the cost is image quality or compression ratio. Here is an example: `ffmpeg -y -r 1/5 -f concat -safe 0 -i ffmcommand.txt -c:v libx264 -vf  fps=25,format=yuv420p -preset veryfast -crf 28 out22.mp4`

Comment: The preset by @GalaDOS will help, but you're going from a rate of 1/5 to 25 i.e. 124 duplicates for each frame. You can usually get away with `fps=5`.